# Comparing one value in a list to all values in the list

Tags: python-3.x, astronomy

I am trying to compare the Ra(coordinate) value of each star in a database to all other Ra of the other stars in that same list, and only pull out stars within 1 degree. I uploaded the data fine, and converted. My trouble is actually comparing all values with all the other values. 
I am using a boolean for the loop.

```
for i,r in enumerate(lyrae):
    q=r['ra']-lyrae['ra']
    m=(q<1) & (q>0)
    c=q[m]
    print(r,c)
    for i,r in enumerate(lyrae):
        v=r['dec']-lyrae['dec']
        n=(v<1) & (v>0)
        b=v[n]
        print(i,b)
```

does not seem to work. Also takes forever to load.

Comment: How big is `lyrae`?  Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: It is 700 different stars right now but I am trying to make it so that does not matter as much. The data will be growing in size soon.

Comment: Could you show us the first few elements so we have some idea as to the structure of the data?

Answer (score 0):

See if this is doing what you meant? You can save a lot of computation time by using efficient built-in/numpy/scipy functions. For example     `m=(q<1) & (q>0)` can be replaced with `abs(q) < 1` (also, when you want to find all objects within 1 degree, `m=(q<1) & (q>0)` should be `m=(q<1) & (q>-1)`).

To correctly find the objects in spherical polar coordinates, you need to find the great circle distance, otherwise, the calculation will fail near the poles and at the cyclic boundary (i.e. (0.1, 10.2) and (359.9, 10.1) ).

If you want to crossmatch between two huge catalogues(e.g. both are 10^9 lines), this is not the way to go because of the inefficient code. However, given one of your catalogue is only ~700 lines, the development time for an efficient search function will probably be much longer than the search itself.

```
import numpy as np

# Set arbitrary size for a reference catalogue and a RR Lyrae cataloge
cat_size = 1000000
lyrae_size = 1000

# Draw sample randomly in a cartesian plane for the catalogue
# (1) RA, (2) Dec and (3) unique ID
ra_cat = np.random.random(cat_size) * 360.
dec_cat = np.random.random(cat_size) * 180. - 90.
id_cat = np.arange(cat_size)

# Draw sample randomly in a cartesian plane for the RR Lyrae catalogue
ra_lyrae = np.random.random(lyrae_size) * 360.
dec_lyrae = np.random.random(lyrae_size) * 180. - 90.
id_lyrae = np.arange(lyrae_size)

def great_circle_distance(ra1, dec1, ra_list, dec_list):
    '''
    Finding the great circle distance between given points and the list of
    points given in equatorial coordinates. Note: this from cosine rule, which
    is not the most accurate way to find the great circle distance.
    Input:
    ra1, dec1 - the reference point in degrees
    ra_list, dec_list - is the list of object positions in degrees
    Output:
    list of distances between the reference point and the list of objects
    in units of degrees.
    '''
    ra1 = np.radians(ra1)
    dec1 = np.radians(dec1)
    ra2 = np.radians(ra_list)
    dec2 = np.radians(dec_list)
    # Great circle distance in radians
    dist = (np.arccos(np.sin(dec1) * np.sin(dec2) +
                      np.cos(dec1) * np.cos(dec2) * np.cos(ra1 - ra2)))
    return np.degrees(dist)

# Loop through the RR Lyrae catalogue
for i, position in enumerate(zip(ra_lyrae, dec_lyrae)):
    # Get the (RA, Dec) from zipped position
    ra, dec = position
    # Consider only objects within a 2x2 degree box
    mask_candidate = (np.abs(ra_cat - ra) < 1.) | (np.abs(dec_cat - dec) < 1.)
    # Get the distance between the RR Lyrae star to the objects in the box
    distance = great_circle_distance(
        ra, dec, ra_cat[mask_candidate], dec_cat[mask_candidate]
        )
    # Select all objects within 1 degree radius
    mask_final = (distance < 1.)
    # Get the unique ID of the catalogue objects
    id_cat_matched = id_cat[mask_candidate][mask_final]
    # print/save/further analysis with the list of matched objects
    print 'lyrae id: ' + str(i+1) + ' matched with catalogue id: ' + str(id_cat_matched)
```